# curl No Match in YouTube -- returns null

Tags: php, curl, youtube

But another server returns content normally..

```
$URL = http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$this->VideoId.'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US


function curlGet($URL) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 

$contents = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo ' er: ' . curl_error($ch)  ;
}
    // get content
    echo $contents ;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: If the same *exact* code works on one server and not another, the problem probably isn't the code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the options to see the Request and Response headers.
It is a good idea to include CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION if your url is redirected.

Something like this will help find problems.

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch)){
      $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }
  else {
    $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
    $responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
    $data= substr($data,$skip);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $info = var_export($info,true);
  }
  echo $responseHeader;
  echo $info;
  print_r($data);
```

Comment: the curl mutch normal the broblem not in curl ... but in server of youtube ??!!

Comment: I had no problem getting the video_info except `get_video_info?&video_id='` should not have the `&` and should be `get_video_info?video_id='`.  You need to know why it is not working.  I gave you the options that return more details like the request and response headers

Comment: it return data ? or return null?